# regex selecting from html

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have this kind of text in which I am looking to extract following text

```
Company Name ASSOCIATES LLP
                    18-20, FLOOR,, BUILDING,
                    K MARG, NEW - 110001
                    Delhi
                    +(91)124-0000000
                    email@EMAIL.COM
```

Here is the code block
The regex I am using is `/Name and address of the Employer(.*)<p>/` but this is making the selection till last `<p>`

```
<p><b>Certificate under Section 203 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 for tax deducted at source on salary
            </b></p>
        <p><b>Name and address of the Employer
            </b></p>
        <p>Company Name ASSOCIATES LLP
            18-20, FLOOR,, BUILDING,
            K MARG, NEW - 110001
            Delhi
            +(91)124-0000000
            email@EMAIL.COM
        </p>
        <p><b>Name and address of the Employee
            </b></p>
        <p>EMPLOYEE NAME
            EMPLOYEE ADDRESS HERE
        </p>
        <p><b>PAN of the Deductor
            </b></p>
        <p>ACHFS9000A
        </p>
        <p><b>TAN of the Deductor
            </b></p>
        <p>DELS50000E
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to extract the content of `p` tag that is next sibling of the `p` node having `b` subnode with contents containing `Name and address of the Employer` with this query:

```
$xp->query("//p[contains(./b, 'Name and address of the Employer')]");
```

See PHP sample code:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<p><b>Certificate under Section 203 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 for tax deducted at source on salary
        </b></p>
    <p><b>Name and address of the Employer
        </b></p>
    <p>Company Name ASSOCIATES LLP
        18-20, FLOOR,, BUILDING,
        K MARG, NEW - 110001
        Delhi
        +(91)124-0000000
        email@EMAIL.COM
    </p>
    <p><b>Name and address of the Employee
        </b></p>
    <p>EMPLOYEE NAME
        EMPLOYEE ADDRESS HERE
    </p>
    <p><b>PAN of the Deductor
        </b></p>
    <p>ACHFS9000A
    </p>
    <p><b>TAN of the Deductor
        </b></p>
    <p>DELS50000E
    </p>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query("//p[contains(./b, 'Name and address of the Employer')]");
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/gsvG2z)

Comment: The data is always different, constant is the name between `<b>` like `Name and address of the Employer`